# Get datagridview index after programmatically selecting row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a button when pressed will automatically select certain row.

```
    dgv.ClearSelection()
    dgv.Rows(2).Selected = True
```

However the selectionchanged event does not fire when I try to select a programmatically. Is there any way around it?

Comment: Can you give us more details? Or maybe show some more of your code.
Because from what I have seen so far, your solution should work.

Comment: I agree with lukas2. This code works, it fires selection changed twice. Once for ClearSelection and once for Setting the row as selected.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. You would need to give us more of your code in order to find the problem. How did you define your selection changed event?

```
     Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
   'Code
End Sub
```

Does it look like that?